# Split Router in Express SubDomain

Tags: node.js, express

Most of the time when we want to split router in node.js Express app we do like this...

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

Then, load the router module in the app:

```
var birds = require('./birds')

// ...

app.use('/birds', birds)
```

However, in **express-subdomain**, Is there any way to split router for birds in sub-domain like above does ???

```
var router = express.Router();

//api specific routes 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.get('/birds', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        { name: "Brian" }
    ]);
});
```

Then, load the router module in the app: **(this is not allow me to split more router ??? )**

```
app.use(subdomain('api', router));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use router.use(), is solved my problem.

```
var router = express.Router();
var birds = require('./birds')

//api specific routes 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.use('/birds', birds);
```